# Azure Event hub to API endpoints

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, protocol-buffers

I have joined new project recently and here they are reviving the data from event hub and using spark, transformations are applied after that they are converting the data to protobuff could anyone help me what is protobuff and why they have used here?

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf, is a method for serializing structured data, similar to XML or JSON. Developed by Google, Protobuf is designed to be a language-agnostic, extensible mechanism for serializing structured data. It is a binary format that is both compact and efficient, making it particularly suitable for high-performance scenarios such as data serialization in distributed systems, storage, and communication protocols.